# Style <li> to behave like a <div>

Tags: css

I'd like to make use of unordered list for many reasons like using drag n drop jquery plugins and other effects like that.

The issue i'm facing is that `<li>` behave oddly when putting stuff in it.. What a robust CSS to make `<li>` tags behave like `<div>` tags but still keep the vertical ordering style?

Comment: Can you explain behave like `<div>`?

Comment: I think what you are needing is to set your `li`s to `display:block` see if that corrects any problems you are having.

Comment: Define 'behave like'? What styles do you want changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one simple way:

```
ul, li {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
li{
display:block;
}
```

gl

Comment: `display: block` is the default; there's only any point in specifying it if you're making `li` display as something other than `block`, which is not common (and generally intended).

Comment: @Gerry no it isn't. `display: list-item;` is the default.

Comment: The default is `display: list-item;`

Comment: Hmm, yes, I'd forgotten about that. I believe in old browsers it used to be `block` was the default? But I think just changing it to `display: block` is unlikely to do all that's desired?

Comment: well i gave an answer from the little facts i got cant do more then that unfortuntly